# Access Version Info for Project

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, versioning

I would like to display what version my App is in on the UI.  It looks like I set that in *Properties --> Application --> Assembler Information*.

- Is that correct?
- Do I manually increment that upon
  releases?
- How do I access that
  programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the assembly version is set that way. To display it in the UI, you can retrieve it with:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

For an example of how to read more info, simply add the standard AboutBox to a (dummy) project, and look at the source. Some of those elements are more readily available as Application properties though.

Comment: standard AboutBox?  Is that a ToolBox component?

Comment: No, an Item Template. Select Project, Add New item, Widows Forms section

Answer (score 0):

Or in System.Windows.Forms:

```
Application.ProductVersion
```